# AWS Classic Loadbalancer dynamic port mapping for ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elastic-load-balancer, amazon-ecs

Currently, it's not possible for one CLB to load balance two distinct TCP services running in the same multinode ECS cluster (confirmed by AWS support).

- Does anyone know a way around that?
- Does anyone from AWS have an approximate date (like is it weeks/months/years) for this feature (dynamic port mapping for TCP ports)?

Context:
Suppose i have a custom TCP server. I would like to run this server for each customer, a single container instance per customer and have those services exposed to the outside world.
Ideally ECS, for each service, would add a TCP listener in CLB that routes traffic to a specific EC2:port instace (the port pair does not matter, the important part is for it to be reachable from the outside).

Thank you

Comment: AWS employee here. If you need to know about specific roadmap requests for a particular service you should talk to the account manager for your AWS account and request a meeting with an AWS representative under mutual NDA. Otherwise you should watch the announcements coming out at AWS Summits and AWS re:Invent for official release announcements.

Comment: thank you Nathan, I might try that though I am not a big customer yet so I would not want to impose :) your tech support is already very high quality (actually best tech support i've ever seen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be happy to know that a new type of load balancer was just released called Network Load Balancer (NLB). This should solve your problem!

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-network-load-balancer-effortless-scaling-to-millions-of-requests-per-second/

Comment: Yes i am very happy :), exactly what i needed, saw it on HN this morning, i was just about to answer my own question :)

Comment: There have been multiple issues with NLB healthcheck reported such as https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=805080. I wonder NLB is actually an solution (I could not make it work with exactly the same issue in the forum topic).

Comment: if your containers restart over and over because of failed healthchecks (happened to me) try setting "HealthCheckGracePeriodSeconds: 600" for your service. this tells ECS to ignore failed healthchecks in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

For TCP communication between services running on dynamic ports most AWS customers use thick client load balancing with a solution like linkerd, consul, or weaveworks (which provides an overlay network). You can also use DNS based service discovery.

There is a list of service discovery mechanisms that integrate well with Amazon ECS here: https://github.com/nathanpeck/awesome-ecs#service-discovery

Comment: thank you for the response, unfortunately, it's not about inter service communication, i need those tcp ports accessible from outside. Sort of like when you do a "rebuild with ssh" in CircleCI, you get an ip/port that you can ssh into from the outside. I need the same thing (though not ssh)

Comment: In that case you will unfortunately have to use the classic load balancer with a statically assigned port. As of now (Sept 2017) there is currently no way to have dynamic ports with a classic load balancer. This does limit you to only running one container of a particular type on an instance, but if you have multiple types of containers you can still combine them on a single instance.